# How to replace Template variables using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, templates

I have an app which stores user-generated email template in DB. The template uses same delimiters as handlebar.

How can I render this template?

Say user has created an invoice email template (using CKEditor & exposed template variables) which I am supposed to send at the time of creating an invoice. I will be saving this template in DB TEXT. Now how do I initialize this template & send the mail.

Is there a Nodejs function or package which can replace the template variable?

Thanks

Lajpat

Comment: Something like [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)?

Comment: Point is the template is not stored in a ejs or html file. It is saved in DB as TEXT & retrieved at run-time for rendering email. EJS JADE they all need .ejs .jade extension files as reference to render the page. While my template is stored as TEXT

Comment: looks like you'll have to use and build `new RegExp()` to parse and replace the template in real time.